# Leader Boards in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, leaderboard

I am looking to create a leader board for work to encourage a bit of competitiveness and a general moral boost for the teams. I have created 2 pages, 1 you input data and it does a sum in the back ground for each department and then orders them.

This information should appear on the second page, the leader board itself.

My question is - is it possible to have a delayed "thinking time" for the application where the names and numbers of each department cycle quickly and load from last place to first? Kind-of like a one armed bandit machine in a casino

I am using Java SE8 in netbeans and im unsure if this is possible or if there is an alternative.

Comment: u want to make ur application wait? have you heard of Thread.sleept(long l)?

Comment: @nafas I think hes talking about an on screen animation, like on slot machines where you have three wheels with pictures on, all spinning for a while until they stop in some "random" combination.
Its probably possible, but not so easy assuming you're using swing.  I'd prefer to go Java EE and have a html from end and do some cool javascript.